# How to get value of Excel cell from COM client

Tags: python, excel, com, comtypes

Right now I am failing to retrieve values from Excel cells read by COM and Python using the following code:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
filename=r'testrap.xlsx'
app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(filename)
worksheet = wb.sheets(1)

for row in range(1,11):
    data = worksheet.Cells(row,1).Value
    print(data)
```

I always get

```
comtypes.client.lazybind.NamedProperty object at 0x....
```

printed on the screen instead of the value of the cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation for comtypes](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#properties-with-arguments-named-properties), properties with arguments are accessed using index notation. `wb.Sheets`<sup>[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.sheets?view=excel-pia)</sup> and `worksheet.Cells`<sup>[[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.cells?view=excel-pia)</sup> are properties with arguments and not methods. In addition, `Value`<sup>[[3]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Value_System_Object_)</sup> is [a property with an optional argument](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#properties-with-optional-arguments). So this should work:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
filename=r'testrap.xlsx'
app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(filename)
worksheet = wb.Sheets[1]

for row in range(1,11):
    data = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value()
    print(data)
```

Not on a Windows computer though, so can't test this ATM.